# Selenium with Firefox: Error 500 "Internal Server Error"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, firefox, selenium, runtime-error

I tried to implement Selenium in my c# application and connect to Firefox:

```
selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444,"*firefox", "www.google.com");
        selenium.Start();
```

Selenium RC arguments:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.43.1.jar -port 4444 -role hub -debug -interactive -multiWindow
```

It opens a blank webpage but a few moments later Visual Studio throws me **"500 internal server error in Systeml.Net.WebException".**

Port 4444 is not used and this is the Selenium RC output:

> 13:25:45.789 INFO - Launching a selenium grid server 2014-09-21 13:25:47.146:INFO:osjs.Server:jetty-7.x.y-SNAPSHOT
>
> 2014-09-21 13:25:47.222:INFO:osjsh.ContextHandler:started o.s.j.s.ServletContext
>   Handler{/,null}
>
> 2014-09-21 13:25:47.235:INFO:osjs.AbstractConnector:Started SocketConnector@0.0.
>   0.0:4444 13:25:55.581 INFO - Got a request to create a new session: Capabilities [{browserName=*firefox}]

Comment: What's the full stack trace? Not just the message.

Comment: Selenium RC has been deprecated for several **years** now. Try using Selenium WebDriver.